# Python Requests custom header issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want send custom header with requests library As POST or GET method, but looks like requests add some default values automatically in header like accept-encoding and accept: */*, is there any solution To remove them

```
my_custom_header= {
    'Host': 'www.example.com'
}
r = requests.get('https://www.example.com',headers=my_custom_header)
```

In the r.request.headers you can see some default values like accept-encoding and...

Comment: Why do you think that you need to remove these headers? If you get an error from the server, post it. You're probably trying to solve the wrong "problem". See [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 2):

`requests` merges the [session's default headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) with your custom headers.

A workaround for the `requests` headers is (taken from a [relevant issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5814)):

```
my_custom_header= {
    'Host': 'www.example.com'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {}
    r = s.get(url, headers=my_custom_header)
```

Since `requests` uses `urllib3` for the underlying network transport, `urllib3` also gets a chance to some default headers. To [skip them](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/82d1f1833e9880701f72ad9a50155e20dcc60efd/src/urllib3/util/request.py#L10-L15) you can use:

```
my_custom_header = {
    'Host': 'www.example.com'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {}
    headers = {h: urllib3.util.SKIP_HEADER for h in urllib3.util.SKIPPABLE_HEADERS}
    headers.update(my_custom_header)
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: looks work! but still i see ```Accept-Encoding: identity```

Comment: You're right :) Edited to account for urllib3's default headers.